# Get all folders that contain specific character

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to get all folders and subfolders (dirs not files) that their name contains a specific character. I am using a custom IOFileFilter but seems to be ignored.

```
Collection<File> myFolders = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File(myFilesPath), new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE), new CustomDirectoryFilter());
```

My custom filter is:

```
public class CustomDirectoryFilter extends AbstractFileFilter {
/**
 * Checks to see if the File should be accepted by this filter.
 *
 * @param file  the File to check
 * @return true if this file matches the test
 */

@Override   
public boolean accept(File file) {       
    return file.isDirectory() && file.getName().contains("@");       
}
}
```

I get only the root folder.

Comment: Are you sure that some files contain "@"?  Can you print some debugging in that filter to verify that assumption?

Comment: Yes, I have set up the debugger and indeed it reaches the filter the and returns true for the specific files.

Comment: I think that the filter itself prevents the further searching inside the subfolders.

Comment: `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File(dir), new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY)` try this once.

Comment: Had already tried it but this returns all directories, not only the ones that have the pattern in their name.

Comment: The above line of code is working for me. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sure but you get all directories initially which was my initial problem to solve (ff variable contains files without the "@" as well)

Answer (score 1):

Try using filewalker API.

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/my/path/here")).filter(x->!Files.isRegularFile(x)).filter(x->x.toString().contains("@")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Using common-io FileUtils

```
        List<File> ff = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File("/Users/barath/elasticsearch-6.2.4"), new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
        for(File f : ff){
        if(f.toString().contains("@"))
        System.out.println(f.toString());
        }
```

Comment: It's an old project build on JAVA 6 with Ant, so I cannot use Streams and even adding new dependencies needs extra effort. Thanks though for your response.